# Http 500 error when trying to logout with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a problem with the servlet that I'm making. You have to log into a system and you also need to log out, I use a file register the users. Login works fine, it reads the user from the file, but for some reason logout doesn't. I get an error when I press the logout-button:

[image]

Here is the code for the class LogoutServlet

```
    package nl.hu.sp.lesson1.dynamicexample;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        RequestDispatcher rd = null;

        try {
            String data = null;
            File file = new File(
                    "C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/webapps/LoginAssignment/loggedusers.txt");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] de = data.split(" ");
                if (de[0].equals("vimal")) {
                    data.trim();

                    rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("testpage.html");
                }
            }
            rd.forward(req, resp);
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is line 39 in your code?

Comment: rd.forward(req, resp);

Comment: i think req is null in this case so null pointer exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a text file and searching for "vimal", if it is found you are initializing `rd`; if it is not found `rd` is null. It cannot find "vimal" in text file and `rd` becomes null so it throws null pointer exception.

Add null check

```
if (rd != null) {
    rd.forward(req, resp);
}
```